# How to Create a wall of activities (like Facebook wall) in my site, for each user?

Tags: users, social-network

I am building a social network site.
My plan is that every user would be able to write articles, tips, upload pictures, comment to others, like other posts etc.

My question is how can I aggregate all the user different activities in to one page (e.g. wall), so the user and all the other users can see all the activities in one page (similar to facebook wall)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the ability to users to create a relationships.
https://drupal.org/project/user_relationships. You can set up what kind of content is shareable.

Then using https://drupal.org/project/heartbeat you can get activity streams.

Really do yourself a favor and get https://drupal.org/node/1849900. It can save up huge amounts of time, allowing you to set up a facebook-like network in a few hours!

Comment: I saw this book, and it's not exactly what I want. the book does not explain how to build a wall, but other social features.

Comment: Well, by wall, I guess you mean the facebook page where you view all everything your friends are posting right?If that is the case you can do it with the 2 modules I mentioned and it is located on chapter 5 of the book(I am trying to create the same thing today!)

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
But, actually I mean the user specific wall that includes only his specific activities, that he made on the site (tips, comments, articles etc).
Does someone know how to create this individual user wall?

Comment: Note that the Heartbeat module is deprecated: **This project will be deprecated. The future would be in the module Message.** (from the module page)

Answer (score 1):

The [Drupal Wall](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_wall) module is what you're looking for. This matches your requirement.

> **Objective**
>
> To enable the users to get the status posting functionality **just like
>   facebook** status posts and wall posts. Users can upload their status
>   with an image and video.
>
> **Description**
>
> This module allows you to post the status on a user’s profile in the
>   form of text, image or video status. Logged user can post comments on
>   any user’s status. Visitors can only view the status and comments of
>   any user (by default). While the permission of View/ Delete/ Edit can
>   also be set by the administrator. The user can delete only that post
>   or comment which he/ she has submitted to other profile. Posts on
>   user’s own profile can also be easily deleted or edited instantly via
>   AJAX.
>
> Also, it allows the user to like his own status or comments as well as
>   other user’s status with help of a well known FLAG module. The theming
>   of wall status will give you the experience just like the facebook
>   wall.

The [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) also does the same

> Provides status updates / microblogs like Facebook's Wall / News Feed, Twitter's Timeline, and Yammer's Feed. Users can update their own status or write messages to other users, nodes, Organic Groups, taxonomy terms, or other entity types. @mentions and #hashtags are supported, as well as comments on status updates, viewing conversations between users, the ability to "like"/"reply" to/RT a message, automatic updates without page refreshing, and integration with over 20 modules.

Comment: Do we have hashtags functionality in D8?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Heartbeat](https://drupal.org/project/heartbeat) module.

> Heartbeat displays user activity on a website. This module is an API
>   to log activity. The logged data contains message structures,
>   attributes and variables. Once the activity messages exist in the
>   database, they will be parsed and build into activity streams.

Example image looks like this -

[image]

I used this module in D6 for a project in a block & it worked fine for my particular need.

Comment: If choosing Heartbeat, note the warning on the module's page: **This project will be deprecated. The future would be in the module Message.**

Comment: @PatrickKenny - If this module is not going to be supported and there is no other module to replace, you should look into contributing for it in future if you are using it.

Comment: People do complain about free stuff too...LOL

Comment: I was using Heartbeat, but when the maintainer announced its deprecation, I switched to Message, which I found to be much more flexible (though a bit more difficult to set up).  Heartbeat works reasonably well for D7, but I just think it's important to note that it has been announced that the module is deprecated when recommending it.